# How can I maintain a list of ListView items in ArrayAdapter that have been visible?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have implemented custom listView with arrayAdapter and overrode the getView() function,

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    DealItemHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new DealItemHolder();

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (DealItemHolder)row.getTag();
        // Data filling
    }

    return row;
}
```

if I use this function to maintain the list of items that have been visible what condition should I check if the row generated in this method was visible, is there any other method I could use to achieve my goal? I have been searching a lot and still unable to find any help
Kindly point me to right direction
Edit:
Let me rephrase it, by the word visible I mean the rows that have been scrolled on screen

Comment: if i understood your question...than u simply check the list size. if its not 0 than rows are visible.

Comment: as top comment said, we require more information about what the problem is and what "Visible" means...

Comment: Sorry for my english, By "visible" I mean the row that has scrolled through the screen or you can say user has watched it on screen